# How to vertically center text next to a radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="radio" checked="" class="regular-radio" name="radio-1-set" id="radio-1-set" /><label for="radio-1-set"></label> Driving
<br />
<input type="radio" class="regular-radio" name="radio-1-set" id="radio-2-set" /><label for="radio-2-set"></label> Public Transit
<br />
<input type="radio" class="regular-radio" name="radio-1-set" id="radio-3-set" /><label for="radio-3-set"></label> Walking
```

CSS:

```
     label {
    display: inline;
}
.radio-1 {
    width: 193px;
}
.button-holder {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}
.regular-radio {
    display: none;
}
.regular-radio + label {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 2px solid #cacece;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 11px;
    position: relative;

}
.regular-radio + label:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FDFDFD;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
    content: " ";
    font-size: 36px;
    height: 8px;
    left: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    width: 8px;
}
.regular-radio:checked + label:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #94E325;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
    content: " ";
    font-size: 36px;
    height: 8px;
    left: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    width: 8px;
}
.regular-radio:checked + label {
    background-color: #e9ecee;
    border: 2px solid #adb8c0;
    color: #99a1a7;
    padding: 11px;
}
.regular-radio + label:active, .regular-radio:checked + label:active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
```

Shows this: http://jsfiddle.net/71vn4uhk/

How can I modify the CSS, so that the text line up vertically next to each radio button and add a little padding left of the text.

Comment: Why do you wrote text outside of the label tags?

Comment: If you put the text inside the label it doesn't look right. I think once I know how to center the text it won't look bad.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/71vn4uhk/5/ This is what it looks like inside... If I can just align it properly and center it than i would love to add it inside the radio button.

Comment: If this is really just about vertical alignment of a radio button with respect to adjacent text, you should try and reduce the problem to a simple case that contains only such elements and the minimal styling you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, you need to place your label text within the label tags.
2. Then you can add necessary padding and styling to your radio buttons.

   http://jsfiddle.net/ca8yzm56/

   ```
   .regular-radio + label {padding-left: 25px;}
   .regular-radio + label:before {top: 16px;}
   .regular-radio:checked + label {padding-left: 25px;}
   .regular-radio:checked + label:after {top: 16px;}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, one of the way. Set this style property of lable's parent element.

```
body {
        vertical-align: top;
        line-height: 26px;
    }
```

[JSFIDDle](http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/71vn4uhk/7/)

Comment: Is there any way to do it without the "body"? I don't want to touch another style. Also I would like to put it inside the checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/71vn4uhk/6/ Can you please help?

Comment: Anything yet? Just curious.